# XPath for an <address> tag using ImportXML in Google Sheets

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm attempting to pull the author name of an article from a news website using importXML and Google Sheets. 
The code looks like this:

```
<div class="grp-content">
        <h2 class="title">
        <div class="excerpt">
        <footer class="byline">
             <address data-aurl="/author/john-smith/" data-aname="JOHN 
               SMITH"></address>
```

I've tried several variations of this path, often returning "imported content is empty":

```
=importxml(A2,"//div[@class='grp-content']/footer/address/@data-aname")
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your XPath is modified, how about this?

```
//div[@class='grp-content']//footer//address/@data-aname
```

And also this might be able to use `//address/@data-aname`

If these were not the result what you want, can you provide the URL of "A2"? I would like to try to test.

### Edit:

From your provided URL, I confirmed the HTML data. In the structure of basic unit of the URL is as follows.

```
<div class="grp-content">
  <h2 class="title">
    <a href="### url ###" title="#####">#####</a>
  </h2>
  <div class="excerpt">
    <p>#####</p>
  </div>
  <footer class="byline">
    <address data-aurl="/author/john-smith/" data-aname="JOHN SMITH"></address>
    <time datetime="2018-12-11T12:34:56Z">11 Dec 2018, 12:34 PM PST</time>
    <a class="byC" href="### url ###" data-dsqi="1234567"></a>
  </footer>
</div>
```

When the values are retrieved from above structure using `IMPORTXML()`, the following results were obtained.

Success

- The information of tabs of each `a` can be retrieved.
- When `//*[@class='byC']/@data-dsqi` and `//a[@class='byC']/@data-dsqi` are used, `1234567` can be retrieved.
- `//*[@class='byC']/../text()` and `//a[@class='byC']/../text()` are used, `11 Dec 2018, 12:34 PM PST` can be retrieved.
- When `//*[@class='excerpt']/../h2` and `//div[@class='excerpt']/../h2` are used, the text value of "h2" can be retrieved.

Failure

- When `//*[@class='byC']/../time"` and `//a[@class='byC']/../time"` are used, `#N/A` is returned.
- When `//*[text()='11 Dec 2018, 12:34 PM PST']` and `//*[text()='11 Dec 2018, 12:34 PM PST']/@datetime` are used, `#N/A` is returned.
- When `//*[@class='byline']/../h2` and `//footer[@class='byline']/../h2` are used, `#N/A` is returned.

#### Workaround

In my environment, the values of `address` couldn't be retrieved. From above results, I resulted that `IMPORTXML()` might not correctly parse `footer`. So as a workaround, I would like to propose to use Google Apps Script instead of `IMPORTXML()`.

### Added:

When Google Apps Script is used for this situation. As a sample script, how about this? This HTML data cannot be directly parsed. So it pulls the part of values including the values you want to use using Parser, and parse and retrieve the values using [XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service).

#### Sample script:

```
function getValuesFromUrl() {
  // Retrieve HTML data
  var url = "https://www.breitbart.com/tag/cnn/";
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

  // Parse HTML data
  var res = Parser.data(html).from("<section id=\"MainW\">").to("</section>").build();
  var decode = XmlService.parse('<r>' + res + '</r>');
  var r = decode.getRootElement().getChildren();

  // Retrieve values
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
    var s = r[i].getChildren("article");
    for (var j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
      var t = s[j].getChildren("div");
      for (var k = 0; k < t.length; k++) {
        var u = t[k].getChildren("footer");
        for (var l = 0; l < u.length; l++) {
          values.push(u[l].getChild("address").getAttribute("data-aname").getValue());
        }
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log(values)
}
```

#### Note:

- In order to use this script, please copy and paste the script to the script editor.
- Before you run the script, please install a GAS library of Parser. You can see the detail information at [here](https://www.kutil.org/2016/01/easy-data-scrapping-with-google-apps.html).
- After installed the library, please run the function of `getValuesFromUrl()`. By this, you can see the values at Log.

#### References:

- [Parser](https://www.kutil.org/2016/01/easy-data-scrapping-with-google-apps.html)
- [XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I tried both and the return was "imported content empty". 

Here's the link I've been using.
https://www.breitbart.com/tag/cnn/

Comment: @Edd Thank you for providing the URL. I confirmed the HTML data retrieved from URL. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? As the result, I propose to use Google Apps Script. I'm really sorry for this situation. If you don't want to use it, please tell me. At that time, my answer has to be removed because my answer is not useful.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! I'm new to XPath and was concerned that I might have overlooked something. Your answer confirmed my results. Much appreciated. Looks like I'll be digging into app scripts.

Comment: @Edd Thank you for your quick reply. I added a sample script of Google Apps Script. If this is useful for you, I'm glad.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for this! Really appreciate you taking the time to help me find a solution.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, Thank you again for all of your help and advice. I'm seeing the following error when attempting to run the script you've provided. The error reads, "Error on line 14: The entity "hellip" was referenced, but not declared. (line 8, file "Code")".

For context, line 14: var s = r[i].getChildren("article");
line 8: var decode = XmlService.parse("<r>" + res + "</r>");

I have very little experience with GAS so the answer may be simple but any help would be appreciated. Thank you again!

Comment: @Edd I'm sorry. I cannot understand about your situation from your comment. I think that the information is required to understand your situation. I would like to solve your issue by knowing correctly your situation. So can you post it as new question? When you post it, please include more information. When you also include the input and output you want, it will help users including me think of your solution. If my skill was more high, I might resolve your issue soon. But I apologize that I cannot do it soon.